# Getting unexpected result when string get too long

Tags: python

I was doing a codewar quiz that needs to get, the longest length of the substring that is the same in reverse, from a given string. The string might just be random letters without space, or it can have digits in it.
the link is [longest_palindrome](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54bb6f887e5a80180900046b/train/python)

I tried to

1. get the element that occurs more than once and stored it into. var c_obj
2. loop each element, and get all the indexes of that element in the string and put it into a list. - From get_index() function
3. pop out the first index, and loop through the rest. eg. s[start_pos:ele_index.pop()]
4. and compare that with the reversed version

Here is the code:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_index(s, c):
    return [i for i, char in enumerate(s) if char == c]

def get_longest_len(ls):
    return max([len(word) for word in ls])

def get_multi_occur_char(s):
    # getting all the letter that occur more than once
    c_obj = Counter(s)
    del c_obj[" "]
    del_keys = [k for k, v in c_obj.items() if v <= 1]
    for k in del_keys:
        del c_obj[k]

    return c_obj

def longest_palindrome (s):
    if not s:
        return 0
    c_obj = get_multi_occur_char(s)
    # if c_obj has no item, it means all letters only occur once, thus not possible to become "word"
    if len(c_obj) == 0:
        return 1
    print(c_obj.keys())
    # for each letter, get [list of index], that letter occurs in the string.
    # and pop the 1st occurence for comparison
    word_ls = []
    for letter in c_obj.keys():
        char_index_ls = get_index(s, letter)
        start_pos = char_index_ls.pop(0)
        # check every possible "word" between, first letter occur and indexes remains in the list
        while char_index_ls:
            possi_word = s[start_pos: char_index_ls.pop() + 1]
            if possi_word == possi_word[::-1]:
                print("{} & {}".format(possi_word, possi_word[::-1]))
                word_ls.append(possi_word)
            else:
                continue
    # since a character dont check with itself, if word_ls is empty
    # it means all character occurs more than once fail the test
    if word_ls:
        return get_longest_len(word_ls)
    else:
        return 1

s = "I like racecars that go fast"
# s = "FourscoreandsevenyearsagoourfaathersbroughtforthonthiscontainentanewnationconceivedinzLibertyanddedicatedtothepropositionthatallmenarecreatedequalNowweareengagedinagreahtcivilwartestingwhetherthatnaptionoranynartionsoconceivedandsodedicatedcanlongendureWeareqmetonagreatbattlefiemldoftzhatwarWehavecometodedicpateaportionofthatfieldasafinalrestingplaceforthosewhoheregavetheirlivesthatthatnationmightliveItisaltogetherfangandproperthatweshoulddothisButinalargersensewecannotdedicatewecannotconsecratewecannothallowthisgroundThebravelmenlivinganddeadwhostruggledherehaveconsecrateditfaraboveourpoorponwertoaddordetractTgheworldadswfilllittlenotlenorlongrememberwhatwesayherebutitcanneverforgetwhattheydidhereItisforusthelivingrathertobededicatedheretotheulnfinishedworkwhichtheywhofoughtherehavethusfarsonoblyadvancedItisratherforustobeherededicatedtothegreattdafskremainingbeforeusthatfromthesehonoreddeadwetakeincreaseddevotiontothatcauseforwhichtheygavethelastpfullmeasureofdevotionthatweherehighlyresolvethatthesedeadshallnothavediedinvainthatthisnationunsderGodshallhaveanewbirthoffreedomandthatgovernmentofthepeoplebythepeopleforthepeopleshallnotperishfromtheearth"
print(longest_palindrome(s))
```

It worked at first when I was just using shorter string, all tests pass when I submit, except the last one, which is the long string I commented out. When I tried it, the result's getting strange:

1. when I execute it, I get 2(the correct answer was 7)
2. when I cut the string into half, I got 5
3. when I do a s.lower() in the function I got 1

```
def longest_palindrome (s):
    s = s.lower()
```

4. when I put "asdsa" at the front part of the string, it got searched(result 5)
5. but when I put that into the middle of the string, the result went back to 2

I thought there might be an error in function that doesn't show, so I tried to move the code out of it, but still the same. I couldn't find where the problem was.

I used Counter cause I want to get familiar with it. Sorry for my spaghetti code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`possi_word = s[start_pos: char_index_ls.pop() + 1]` only check every possible words between the first letter and the remaining one. When the palindrome start from the letter in the middle, the code will fail. For example,
`s = "aaba"`, your code will first check for `"aaba"` then `"aa"` but will ignore `"aba"`, giving the result 2 instead of 3.

There may be other improvements in your code, but I just change the part of checking possible words to make it work:

```
word_ls = []
for letter in c_obj.keys():
    char_index_ls = get_index(s, letter)
    while char_index_ls:
        # pop the first index, check every words between it and remaining index, then pop the second 
        # one, do the check, then the third ... until the list is empty to check all combinations.
        start_pos = char_index_ls.pop(0) 
        for i in range(len(char_index_ls)):
            possi_word = s[start_pos: char_index_ls[i] + 1]
            if possi_word == possi_word[::-1]:
                print("{} & {}".format(possi_word, possi_word[::-1]))
                word_ls.append(possi_word)
```

Use letter `"a"` in `s = "I like racecars that go fast"` for example, the code will check:

1. `aceca`, `acecars tha` and `acecars that go fa` using first "a" in first for loop.
2. `ars tha`, and `ars that go fa` using second "a" in second for loop.
3. `at go fa` being the last pairs in third for loop

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, somehow my last replying was gone. Thank you so much for your help :D